# mysql not returning records that contain substring

Tags: mysql, sql-like, contains

I have a database emails that has crewEmails which contain email addresses.  I'm trying to get all addresses that contain "comcast" in the address. Here's the sql I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM `emails` WHERE crewEmail like '%{"comcast"}%'
```

but this returns nothing.  I absolutely have comcast email addresses in the database.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `emails` WHERE crewEmail like '%comcast%'

Try this.  I think you accidentally wrapped your string in these { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of brackets :

```
SELECT * FROM `emails` WHERE crewEmail like '%comcast%'
```

Comment: already answered before...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try these SQL syntax, without double quotes around comcast :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE '%$word%'
```

After fields and values substitutions :

```
SELECT * FROM `emails` WHERE `crewEmail` LIKE '%comcast%'
```

Comment: Can you explain the need for the brackets {} with MySQL?   I've never seen that (just '%comcast%' ) and I don't see it here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html  .  This is an email address like "foo.comcast.net" so there are no literal bracket characters.

Comment: @DaveS You're right, it is concerning REGEXP and not (R)LIKE statments. Editing my answer.